# Are ListviewItems ever truely deselected?

Tags: vb.net, listview, selecteditem, listviewitem

I have a listview with several items in it. If I have an item selected and click in an empty white space or anywhere else on the form the highlight is removed but .FocusedItem & .SelectedItems still report an item is selected.

I have events that I want to trigger when no listviewitems are selected, but that never seems to occur. How do I detect if no items are selected or does that ever actually happen after that first item gets clicked?

```
Private Sub lstCats_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstCats.SelectedIndexChanged
    If IsNothing(lstCats.FocusedItem) Then
        DisableGUI()
    Else
        EnableGUI()
        DisplayQuestions()
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically `DisableGUI()` will never execute.
Thanks!

Comment: if the LV client area is full (no empty area) it is difficult for the user to unselect all

Comment: This is true. I edited my question above to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deselect all items in the ListView by clicking on an empty part of the ListView control (that is not on one of the items). For example:

```
Private Sub lstCats_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstCats.SelectedIndexChanged
    If lstCats.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        DisableGUI()
    Else
        EnableGUI()
        DisplayQuestions()
    End If
End Sub
```

Note if you click on an item in the ListView, SelectedItems will be > 0. If you click on the background of the ListView (not on an item), SelectedItems will be = 0. This assumes that there is part of the ListView control that does not contain an item.

Comment: This does remove the highlight of the item, but if you check .selecteditems or .forcuseditem it still contains a value.

Comment: @JoshLs I tested this by having a button click handler store the value of `ListView1.SelectedItems.Count.ToString` in a label. Clicking the button after selecting an item displayed "1", clicking the button after clicking on a empty part of the ListView displayed "0".

Comment: I was checking on SelectedIndexChanged. `Private Sub lstCats_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstCats.SelectedIndexChanged
        If IsNothing(lstCats.FocusedItem) Then
            DisableGUI()
        Else
            EnableGUI()
            DisplayQuestions()
        End If
    End Sub` DisableGUI() will never execute. Any suggestions on how this could be better handled?

Comment: @JoshLs I edited my answer to show the method that works for me (assuming there is part of the ListView control visible that does not contain an item.

Comment: That does the trick. I just thought my method looked better but obviously doesn't work how I thought it would. Thanks!